# how to handle hange my routes value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have an area and change my route to this

```
 public class WeblogsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
 {
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Weblogs";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Weblogs_default",
            "Weblogs/{controller}/{action}/{blogName}/{post}",
            new { action = "Index", 
                  blogName = UrlParameter.Optional,post=UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

    }
}
```

and it is my index

```
 public ActionResult Index(string blogName,int post)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

it works fine by this:

```
 http://localhost:2927/Weblogs/Blogs?blogName=Myco&Post=3
```

but works not by

```
 http://localhost:2927/Weblogs/Blogs?blogName=Myco
```

what is the problem?

how can i change my rout to works with this URL:

```
 http://localhost:2927/Weblogs/Blogs/Myco/3
```

"myco" is blog name and 3 is post number.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `action` and `controller` tokens from your route. Modify it to be like so:

```
 context.MapRoute(
            "Weblogs_default",
            "Weblogs/Blogs/{blogName}/{post}",
            new { action = "Index", 
                  Controller = "Blogs",
                  blogName = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  post=UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

Comment: thanks it works if i remove action but how can i handle it when no post number is available like this:http://localhost:2927/Weblogs/Blogs/Myco

Comment: Just modify the post argument of your action to make it Nullable<int>. This should do the trick.